# $(...).markdown is not a function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap

Tengo un problema en la compilacion de mardown editor de bootstrap al adaptarlo en angular js con una directiva

```
function markdownEditor() {
  'ngInject';

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require:  'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      $(element).markdown({
          savable:false,
          onChange: function(e){
            ngModel.$setViewValue(e.getContent());
          }
        });

    }
  };
}

export default markdownEditor;
```

al compilar la directiva me da el siguiente error

> $(...).markdown is not a function

Sin compilar los archivos todo funciona de maravilla y me muestra el editor sin ningun problema

Comment: Lee https://github.com/toopay/bootstrap-markdown/issues/101

Comment: e tratado de hacer lo mismo pero igual me da error al compilar mis archivos sin la compilación todo perfecto

Comment: Estp es mi codido luego de la compilacion   $(t).markdown({
        savable: !1,
        onChange: function(e) {
            r.$setViewValue(e.getContent())
        }
    })

Comment: Aparentemente te has olvidado de incluir el `plugin` al momento de compilar.

Comment: Ciertamente era un problema de organizacion de archivos en gulp a la hora de compilar no me ordenaba los archivos js como debia ser gracias por la respuesta